# String Concatenation Convention

Tags: php, coding-style, psr-2

What is the best practice in concatenating multiple strings? What I did is every concatenation will be on the next line? I'm following the psr-2 80 line limit and the 120 line soft limit.

e.g.

```
return (
    Config::get('url')['base_folder'] .
        Config::get('url')['user_image_folder'] .
            "/{$image_name}.jpg"
);
```

VS

```
return Config::get('url')['base_folder'] . Config::get('url')['user_image_folder'] . "/{$image_name}.jpg";
```

Comment: I think there is no "right" answer to this. My opinion is that the first example is more readable (maybe loose the increasing indentation), and makes commiting changes to a VCS easier (diffs are clearer than if you made a change in the one-line version, i.e. where in the whole line is the change).

Comment: This question does not belong on SO. It has nothing to do with a problem and is completely opinion based. I don't think it will even fit on code review.